# Vue Vite scoped css won't assign style

Tags: css, vue.js, vite

I'm trying to add a background-image to a view in vue vite. I don
't want to set this background-image on every view so I tried to add it inside the views site using a scoped css style.

But once I assign scoped to the style tag it won't use the style...

Example code which doesn't work:

```
<style lang="css" scoped>
  body{
    background: url("../../assets/images/background.jpg") !important;
  }
</style>
```

Once I remove the scoped it would work but it would add the background to every view which shouldn't happen. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html)

> When a `<style>` has the scoped attribute, its CSS will apply to elements of the current component only.

This means thst only the elements in your `<template>` will get the style and since there is no `<body>` in your template, then it doesn't get style.